# Import csv files to google sheets from shiny apps.io download

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, tableau-api, shinyapps

I have built a shiny apps.io server that takes csv files from the shiny apps project folder and renders them as simple tables with a download handler for each.

My department want to display / manipulate these tables in Tableau (don't ask why). This is a little tricky as they do not play well together. As a middle-ground, I have attempted to use google sheets. The workflow therefore is:

1. shiny app.io publishes tables
2. google sheet reads url of download handler (ie right click - copy link address)
3. Tableau reads in table from google sheets

The issue is that the url of the download button is unique based on each session, usually in the format:

https://shinyapps.io/app/session/session_id/download/downloadPlot

Meaning google sheets cannot be pointed to it as every visits url is unique.

Is there a way to keep the download csv url static? Perhaps by changing the arguments passed to the download handler or using a different widget?

I have attempted to use embedded html using tags$a but the issues remains the same.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to write/read the data to/from a common database ? There might even be a quick and easy way for them to set it up from within tableau.

Comment: That was one possibility I was considering. can shiny apps.io be configured to write to a mongoDB database and this could act as an intermediary instead?

Comment: It seems possible : [7. MongoDB (local or remote)](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html#mongodb)